# React native monorepo with Microsoft appcenter

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center, lerna, nrwl-nx, code-push

How can I build / distribute react native apps on appcenter using a monorepo? I've tried lerna and nx but no luck with either.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried with NX, just with Lerna only. I was able to do so within a post-clone script.

My project set up is:

packages

- backend
- reactnativeapp
- shared

I select the package.json within the React Native app's package / directory:

[image: package.json within app center]

Here is the `appcenter-post-clone.sh` build script, with appropriate comments in the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Create fake yarn lock so appcenter uses Yarn instead of npm install
touch yarn.lock

# Navigate to root directory
cd ../../

# Add global dependencies 
yarn global add @aws-amplify/cli # for aws amplify - exclude if not using
yarn global add lerna

# Private github package permissions - exclude or update based on your needs
npm config set @apptractive:registry https://npm.pkg.github.com
npm config set always-auth true
npm config set //https://npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken="${NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}"

# Install dependencies using Lerna
yarn run bootstrap --include-dependencies

# Copy RN CLI that Ms App Center depends on
mkdir -p packages/reactnativeapp/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/
cp node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js packages/reactnativeapp/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js

# Build other packages within monorepo that React Native depends on
cd packages/shared && yarn build
```

I have posted more details on an [App Center Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/278#issuecomment-1251805774), particularly if you are using AWS Amplify also

Answer (score 0):

I'm using NX react native with MS App Center. I did a lot of workaround to make it work. In my opinion, if you using NX, avoid to MS App Center.